# Сервер отправляет данные клиенту когда он выключен

Tags: c, сеть, сокет

Возникли непонимания, для начала объясню что вообще прога делает чтобы вам не пришлось отгадывать что значит мой "код".

---

Прога у меня является обыкновенным клиент-сервером уровня отправь это - получи то и отсоединись. А если быть конкретнее то после подключения к серверу клиент вводит сообщение , дальше это сообщение отправляется серверу, сервер в свою очередь принимает его и отправляет его клиенту, клиент принимает сообщение и функцией puts выводит его на экран. Надеюсь объяснил понятно.

А теперь перейду к проблеме

Код сервера:

```
  while(1)
  {
  socket2=accept(socket1,(struct sockaddr*)&client, 
 (socklen_t*)&len_client);
  printf ("Какой-то пирожок подсоединился %s 
 \n",inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr));
  if (socket2==0)
  {
   printf ("accept\n");
   exit(1);
  }
  while(1)
  {
  if(recv(socket2,buf,sizeof(buf),0)==0)
  {
  printf ("Клиент отключился\n");
  break;
  }
  send(socket2,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
  }
 }
  return 0;
 }
```

Код клиента:

```
 while (1)
 {
 puts("Что вы хотите отправить серверу?");
 gets(buf);
 send(socket1, buf,sizeof(buf), 0);
 recv(socket1,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
 puts(buf);
 }
```

Сначала фото:

Проблему я выделил белым цветом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: Почему когда я отключаю сервер, клиенту приходят данные от него(я понимаю что нужно сокет закрывать, но все же), почему они приходят? Я же отключил сервер, а если опять сервер включить то он запустится на том же порту без проблем.

Постарался как можно понятнее описать проблему.

---

Код сервера целиком:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <arpa/inet.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main (void)
 {
  char buf[1000];
  int socket1,socket2;
  socket1=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  if (socket1==0)
  {
   printf ("socket\n");
    exit(1);
   }

 struct sockaddr_in net,client;
  net.sin_family=AF_INET;
  net.sin_port=htons(32222);
  net.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  if(bind(socket1,(struct sockaddr*)&net,sizeof(net))==-1)
  {
   printf ("bind\n");
   exit(1);
  }

  if(listen(socket1,3)==-1)
   {
   printf ("listen\n");
   exit(1);
  }
  int len_client=sizeof(client);
  while(1)
  {
  socket2=accept(socket1,(struct sockaddr*)&client, 
 (socklen_t*)&len_client);
  printf ("Какой-то пирожок подсоединился %s 
 \n",inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr));
  if (socket2==0)
  {
    printf ("accept\n");
   exit(1);
  }
 // memset(buf,'\0',999);
  while(1)
  {
  if(recv(socket2,buf,sizeof(buf),0)==0)
   {
  printf ("Клиент отключился\n");
  break;
 }
 send(socket2,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
   }
 }
  return 0;
 }
```

---

Код клиента целиком:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 struct sockaddr_in addr;
 int main (void)
 {
  char buf[1000];
  int socket1;
  socket1=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  if (socket1==0)
  {
   printf ("socket\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port=htons(32222);
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  if (connect(socket1,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr))==0)
  {
   printf ("Мы подсоединились!!!\n");
  }
  else
  {
   printf ("Вот досада, подсоединиться не получилось\n");
   exit(1);
  }
  while (1)
  {
   //memset(buf,'\0',999);
   puts("Что вы хотите отправить серверу?");
   gets(buf);
   send(socket1, buf,sizeof(buf), 0);
   recv(socket1,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
   puts(buf);
  }
   //recv(socket1,buf,sizeof(buf),0);

  return 0 ;
 }
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что правильно понимаете каким образом сообщается программе о разрыве соединения?

Comment: @0andriy, ну я понимаю как это исправить , просто обрабатываю функцию 'recv', если она возвращает 0 то программа закрывается, но когда я не делаю обработку ошибок, почему выключенный сервер отправляет данные клиенту?

Comment: Саму **проблему** я так и не понял. Распишите последовательность действий (и видимых результатов) подробнее (картинка статична, в какой момент какие строки на ней появились и что именно вас смущает не ясно)

Comment: @avp, сначала я выключаю сервер, потом ввожу и отправляю данные , по идее эти данные не должен обрабатывать сервер (ведь он выключен ), но он все равно их принимает и отправляет обратно, потом, когда я второй раз ввожу данные в клиенте и отправляю их серверу , сервер уже не отвечает и программа клиент вырубается

Comment: Тогда см. ответ @Harry / Т.е. на самом деле данные не отправлялись и ни откуда не получались. / Минимальная проверка -- написать `buf[0] = 0;` сразу после `send()` / А с какой целью вы пересылаете весь буфер, а не реально введенные `gets()` данные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думается мне, что вот тут

```
while (1)
  {
   //memset(buf,'\0',999);
   puts("Что вы хотите отправить серверу?");
   gets(buf);
   send(socket1, buf,sizeof(buf), 0);
   recv(socket1,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
   puts(buf);
  }
```

у вас происходит следующее - когда клиент *не может* отправить-принять (по любой причине), вы об этом даже не подозреваете! - вы же *не проверяете* возвращаемые значения `send` и `recv` :( - и просто выводите свою же строку. И пребываете в (ложной) уверенности, что все работает...

Хотите убедиться? Проверяйте возврат `send` и `recv`.

Если категорически не хотите проверять коды возврата - да просто занулите или перепишите свою строку между `send` и `recv` и посмотрите, что будет на экране...

P.S. Хотя почему он вас не посылает еще в функции `connect` - непонятно...

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ:-)

Answer (score 2):

Вот у Вас в тексте клиента есть такая строка:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

А потом вы пытаетесь соединится с этим самым addr:

```
connect(socket1,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr)
```

Как вы думаете, к чему это приведёт? С каким именно хостом будет установлено соединение?! В *man 2 connect* написано:

> Системный   вызов   connect()  устанавливает  соединение  с  сокетом, 
>   заданным  файловый дескриптором sockfd, ссылающимся на адрес addr.

как можно установить соедиенеи с INADDR_ANY?! На самом деле, здесь нужно указать **конкретный** адрес **конкретного** сервера. Как то так:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_aton(host)
```

Про эту функцию в *man* говорится:

> inet_aton() преобразует адрес Интернет-узла cp из числовой формы
>   записи  IPv4  с  точками (IPv4  numbers-and-dots)  в  двоичную  форму 
>   (с  сетевым порядком байт) и сохраняет её в структуре, на которую
>   ссылается inp.  inet_aton()  возвращает  ненулевое  значение,  если
>   адрес  правильный,  и  ноль,  если  нет.

Comment: Да что вы так разругались из-за моей привязки клиента к серверу)) Я понимаю что это не должно работать , но это работает)) И поэтому я так оставил на время, ибо есть проблемы по важнее. Но за ответ благодарю:)

Comment: Хотя , у меня же всего один адрес хоста `127.0.0.1`, поэтому я думаю что это не страшно))